# PHP base64_encode adding strange character at the end of string

Tags: php, cookies, base64

I´m using an array, which I encode into json, than into BASE64, save it on a Cookie, to be later on retrieved.
The actual string is:

```
{"insert":0,"delete":0}
```

In PHP I have:

```
$Sync = json_encode($update);
setcookie('Sync',strtr(base64_encode($Sync), '+/', '-_'), 0, "/");
```

The Cookie is being stored as:

```
eyJpbnNlcnQiOjEsImRlbGV0ZSI6MH0%3D
```

That final "%3D" should be "=" so to fill the rest of the base64, nad therefore return strange characters, but I can´t get it right. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "the value of the cookie is automatically URLencoded when sending the cookie, and automatically decoded when received" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780170/what-does-the-value-of-the-cookie-is-automatically-urlencoded-when-sending-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the docs on php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849) the top comment provides two functions that should help you (similar to your implementation as well :))

> For anyone interested in the 'base64url' variant encoding, you can use this pair of functions:
>
> ```
> <?php 
> function base64url_encode($data) { 
>   return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
> } 
>
> function base64url_decode($data) { 
>   return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT)); 
> } 
> ?>
> ```

Within your implementation, it looks like you need to wrap 
`strtr(base64_encode($Sync), '+/', '-_'), 0, "/")` with `rtrim`, like so:

```
rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($Sync), '+/', '-_'), 0, "/"), '=')
```

Results: https://3v4l.org/5D1Mk