# json_encode() issue and storing in cookie issue in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I am converting `json_encode`; It is converting it in correct format, but when I am storing it in cookie; format get changed. I want to store in cookie as it is.

***JSON STRING:***

```
{
"ID": "0",
  "basicAddress": {
    "ID": "0",
    "Line1": "327 S Main St",
    "Line2": "",
    "Line3": "",
    "City": "Fitzgerald",
    "ZipCode": "31750",
    "StateProv": "",
    "Country": "",
    "stateProv": "GA"
  },
  "Name": "",
  "Latitude": "31.7114886",
  "Longitude": "-83.25471970000001",
  "IsPreferred": "false"
}
```

***AFTER STORING IN COOKIE:***

```
%7B%22ID%22%3A%220%22%2C%22basicAddress%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A%220%22%2C%22Line1%22%3A%22327+S+Main+St%22%2C%22Line2%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Line3%22%3A%22%22%2C%22City%22%3A%22Fitzgerald%22%2C%22ZipCode%22%3A%2231750%22%2C%22StateProv%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Country%22%3A%22%22%2C%22stateProv%22%3A%22GA%22%7D%2C%22Name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Latitude%22%3A%2231.7114886%22%2C%22Longitude%22%3A%22-83.25471970000001%22%2C%22IsPreferred%22%3A%22false%22%7D
```

[image]

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: $address=json_encode($address);
setcookie('address',$address,time() +50000,"/");

Comment: Yeah, cookie values will be URL encoded, that is the expected behaviour. Clarify at which point you expect something else.

Comment: From where you are accessing the cookies? using javascript or php?

Comment: It will be access by other domain in ASP

Comment: PHP automatically [encodes cookies values, and decodes them on retrieving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780170/what-does-the-value-of-the-cookie-is-automatically-urlencoded-when-sending-the/41780547#41780547).

Comment: It's not correct way for me to decode on retrive because it will be access by other domain which is in ASP and they are storing it as i want

Comment: You must encode them. That's how the cookies (and HTTP headers in general) works. Make the ASP side urldecode them (if it is not done automatically).

Comment: Check again ihave attached screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution and it's working absolutely correct as i want

```
$address={
"ID": "0",
  "basicAddress": {
    "ID": "0",
    "Line1": "327 S Main St",
    "Line2": "",
    "Line3": "",
    "City": "Fitzgerald",
    "ZipCode": "31750",
    "StateProv": "",
    "Country": "",
    "stateProv": "GA"
  },
  "Name": "",
  "Latitude": "31.7114886",
  "Longitude": "-83.25471970000001",
  "IsPreferred": "false"
};
cookie_expire_time=30000;
header("Set-Cookie: address=$address; Domain=.example.com;Path=/; Max-Age=".cookie_expire_time.";");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour for `setcookie` to URL-encode the value. You can use [`setrawcookie`](http://php.net/setrawcookie) to avoid that automatic encoding, but then you need to ensure yourself that your cookies are correctly formed to be HTTP compliant.

Comment: It's shows below :
 Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => Cookie values cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014'
    [file] => /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/asystu/functions.php
    [line] => 303
)

Comment: Well, there you go… looks like your ASP variant is producing technically invalid cookies (which are nonetheless begrudgingly handled by browsers).