# Do I need to encode window.location.hostname when saving to cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss

my Fortify scan is complaining about saving unvalidated data to cookie.
To be exact it does not like that I use `window.location.hostname` directly when saving to cookie.
Is is false positive? Do I really need to encode `window.location.hostname` like in example below?

`const encodedHostname = encodeURI(window.location.hostname);`

Comment: Unless the cookie code does the encoding, yes

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate? I thought hostname can be only like `www.example.com`? How can malicious code be inserted there?

Comment: More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780170/what-does-the-value-of-the-cookie-is-automatically-urlencoded-when-sending-the

Comment: I assume Fortify does not know what data you actually enter into the cookie and is complaining

Comment: Thanks, I ended up encoding `window.location.hostname` just in case. Thanks for the link, still they mention there about PHP's setcookie auto-encoding, but I wasn't able to confirm same thing happens for JS's `document.cookie`